# Test works on local Windows machine but fails on Linux server

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, jar

I have this test:

```java
@Test
void testHeader() {
        
    String inputFile = ".\\src\\main\\resources\\binaryFile";
    MDHeader addHeader = new MDHeader();
        
    try (
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    ) {
     
        long fileSize = new File(inputFile).length();
        byte[] allBytes = new byte[(int) fileSize];
        inputStream.read(allBytes);
        ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record = new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>("foo", allBytes);
        ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> hdr = addHeader.addMDHeader(record);
                
        for (Header header : hdr.headers()) {
            assertEquals("mdpHeader", header.key());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        assert (false);
    }
}
```

The test succeeds when run locally through Eclipse on my Windows desktop but it fails at `com.me.be.HeaderTests.testMDHeader(HeaderTests.java:81)` when trying to build the jar on a Linux server. That's the line `assert (false)`. I haven't got any more information on the issue yet but was wondering if it could be the backslashes in `inputFile` in a Linux environment?

Comment: if you file is in `src/main/resources` and you need to read in tests, then what you are doing is very wrong. There is a reason people put files in that directory and it is exactly the opposite reasons of how you do it now

Comment: It could be the backslashes. It would be helpful if you would know the exception that is thrown. IMHO your code (`catch(Exception e) { assert(false); }` is bad test design. If you don't catch exceptions (and instead declare your test method to `throws Exception`) the test would still fail when an exception is thrown, but the test framework would give you much better error reporting.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Eugene how should I do it? Thomas Kläger I'll look at ow I can make this a better test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java on Windows and Linux will both accept `/` as path separator, whereas Linux does not like `\\` as a path separator - so treats the whole string as ONE path component, not 4 parts as you'd expect:

```
String inputFile = "./src/main/resources/binaryFile";
```

However for file handling it is better to use `java.nio.Path` or `java.io.File` in place of `String`.

```
WINDOWS
jshell> Path.of("./src/main/resources/binaryFile")
$2 ==> .\src\main\resources\binaryFile

Linux
jshell> Path.of("./src/main/resources/binaryFile")
$1 ==> ./src/main/resources/binaryFile
```

You can also use `Path.of` without any file separator for any OS:

```
Path p = Path.of("src","main","resources","binaryFile");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `File.separator` string is handy to concat into the path string in order to produce an OS independent file path.

```
String inputFile = "." + File.separator + "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "binaryFile";
```

Should give you a cross platform compliant file path.